# Prove that $A\subseteq B\iff \complement B\subseteq \complement A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working with the proof of $A\subseteq B\iff \complement B\subseteq \complement A$, from the book Introduction to Abstract Algebra of Thomas Whitelaw. This is the formal proof of the author (following a Venn Diagram justification).

[image]

Without error on my part, the author proves the direct statement and not the converse. What am I missing here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: every statement in this proof is an "if and only if" statement, and you can simply trace the proof backwards to show the converse

Comment: We have the words "it is equivalent to", which is the same thing as "if and only if". The author assumes you are already familiar with contraposition though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can break down the argument and show that every step can go both ways, i.e., "if and only if".

1. "$A\subseteq B$" if and only if "$x\in A\Longrightarrow x\in B$": this is the definition of subset relation, so it goes both ways.
2. "$x\in A\Longrightarrow x\in B$" if and only if "$x\notin B\Longrightarrow x\notin A$": If you can understand that the second statement is the contrapositive of the first statement, you would also realize that the first statement is the contrapositive of the second statement. Therefore, the statements are equivalent.
3. "$x\notin B\Longrightarrow x\notin A$" if and only if "$x\in \complement B\Longrightarrow x\in \complement A$": this uses the definition of set complements, so it also goes both ways.
4. "$x\in \complement B\Longrightarrow x\in \complement A$" if and only if "$\complement B\subseteq \complement A$": similar to (1), this is the definition of subset relation.